# g2o in ROS creates problems with Csparse

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I downloaded g2o library to use it from inside ROS.
Everything seemed to work well, since writing

```
using namespace g20;
```

and including test library

```
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/block_solver.h"
```

allowed compiling through **rosmake** from inside my package.
Problems arose when I started to write the real g2o code and just one line

```
SparseOptimizer optimizer;
```

caused the following error:

```
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/csparse_helper.h:23:16: fatal error: cs.h: File o directory non esistente
```

Then I updated my system to have Csparse:

```
sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev
```

but I got a message advising me that it's already there.
Finally, I modified my package's CMakeLists file:

```
include_directories(${CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

but nothing changed.
Does anyone how to solve the problem?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83646/g2o-in-ros-creates-problems-with-csparse/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are doing include_directories of CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR, are you successfully calling find_package on CSPARSE first? If so does CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR hold any value? You might have a typo in the variable name. (Not all packages have the same capitalization in CMake rules etc)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-09-28**:
thanks for answer.
I tried to solve problem through an explicit inclusion:
include_directories(/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/CSparse/Include)
include_directories(/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/CSparse/Source)

This seems to work, it should be equivalent to...

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-09-28**:
...
SET(CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR /home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/CSparse/Include /home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/CSparse/Source)
include_directories(${CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR})

am I mistaking? anyway now a bigger problem has figured out: g2o doesn't find its own functions...

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-09-28**:
this is the link to my new post: http://answers.ros.org/question/84746/g2o-doesnt-find-its-own-functions-in-ros/.
If you can help, I'll be very glad. I'm just a newbie... :)))